# SpringBoot NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, jpa

I am building a simple url shortener connected to MongoDB Atlas with a JPA repository, and when I try to save the url data when the request hits the post request, I get the following error: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection.insertOne(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/mongodb/client/result/InsertOneResult;`. According the research, I believe it is a dependency issue but was not able to resolve it.

URL.java:

```
package com.sideproject.urlshortner.model;

import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Data
@Document(collection = "url")
public class URL {
    @Id
    private String id;
    String longURL;
    String shortenedURL;

    public URL(String longURL, String shortenedURL) {
        this.longURL = longURL;
        this.shortenedURL = shortenedURL;
    }

}
```

URLController.java:

```
package com.sideproject.urlshortner.controller;

import com.sideproject.urlshortner.repository.URLRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import com.sideproject.urlshortner.model.URL;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/index")
public class URLController {

    @Autowired
    private URLRepository urlRepository;


    @RequestMapping(value="/urls/", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public URL postURL(@RequestBody URL url) {
        return urlRepository.save(url); // giving the error.
    }
 
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://myname:password@testcluster-scgty.mongodb.net/dbname?retryWrites=true&w=majority
spring.data.mongodb.database=dbname
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sideproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>url-shortner</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>url-shortner</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The Boot parent manages most versions of basic modules for you. Remove the `version` tags.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Would you want to post your answer so I can accept it? If you don't mind :)

Comment: A couple of side notes: Avoid `@Autowired` fields, since they cause all sorts of problems. Since you're using Lombok, just do `@RequiredArgsConstructor` and make the field `private final`. Also, it's general convention to treat acronyms as a single word, so the recommended name is `UrlRepository`.

Comment: These are good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the features of `spring-boot-starter-parent` is that [it manages versions of many common dependencies for you](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-dependency-management), ensuring that the versions of all the different pieces you're using are compatible. In this case, your explicit version is causing incompatibility between Spring Data MongoDB and the MongoDB driver; simply eliminate the `version` tags from your dependencies.

(You may be getting a warning about "overriding managed dependency version"; always pay attention to warnings.)

Answer (score 6):

The issue is you are providing boot starter and mongo driver like below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.6</version>
</dependency>
```

whereas spring-boot-starter-data-MongoDB has a java driver dependency of 4.0.4. So 2 different versions are colliding. just remove your explicit mongo driver dependency.

```
<properties>
    <project.type>multi</project.type>
    <dist.id>spring-data-mongodb</dist.id>
    <springdata.commons>2.3.1.RELEASE</springdata.commons>
    <mongo>4.0.4</mongo>
    <mongo.reactivestreams>${mongo}</mongo.reactivestreams>
    <jmh.version>1.19</jmh.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb uses org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync as dependency, which conflicts with org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver